# Gutenburg InnerBlock single child

Tags: block-editor

I have a custom block called `Custom Card` that takes an `InnerBlock` as a child. The purpose of this is because I want to format the content within the `Custom Card` a very specific way.

The `Custom Card` has three allowed blocks:

- `core/quote`
- `core/video`
- `core/image`

The problem I've run into, is that after a user selects a block they can continue to add more blocks to the same Card. I want to limit the card to allow them to select *one* of the three options they have available. What is some ways I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution to this problem I've implemented using the [renderAppender](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/inner-blocks#renderappender) prop, inspired by Welcher's comment above and [this post over on Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53345956/gutenberg-custom-block-add-elements-by-innerblocks-length).

```
<InnerBlocks
  renderAppender={() => {
    const blocks = select('core/editor').getBlocks();
    const block = find(blocks, ['name', 'NAME_OF_YOUR_BLOCK']);
    // don't return appender if there's one or more blocks:
    if (block && block.innerBlocks.length > 0) return null;
    // otherwise, return default appender
    return (<InnerBlocks.DefaultBlockAppender />);
  }}
/>
```

**Note:** This example is using [lodash find](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find) function to get the block I'm targeting. There may be a better way to do this, but for now it does the job.

Also, be sure to import the `select` function. E.g.

```
import { select } from '@wordpress/data';
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do this at the moment is by using the `renderAppender`prop on`InnerBlocks`. This prop is only available in the Gutenberg plugin until WordPress 5.3 is released. The theory would be to use state in each `CustomCard` to track if there has been a block added, then return false from the `renderAppender` function so the user cannot insert more items.